# Load One Source into Two Targets With Fail condition

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have a single source & two targets Target A & Target B. We want to load Both Tar A first & Tar B. We want the Load to continue In case Either one Fails. Meaning in case  Target A fails, Target B should be loaded and vice versa. We donot want the load to abandon with All or None Scenario. Any options where we query the Source only onetime.  Two independent Job flows is not an option as we want a single pull

Answer (score 0):

In your workflow you can write the output to a staging table in your first session and then query the same staging table in 2 parallel sessions writing to the 2 separate tables, that way you guarantee that it doesn't matter what happens with the unrelated load to each of the targets.

Comment: Staging table is not an option as it would again has to be another point of failure. We are trying to create an active / active system.  Just making sure if we can handle exception and continue with load in a single job flow. Read something like constraint based etc.

Comment: Ok... I get it, you have a requirement for redundancy between 2 target databases and so want to load them both simultaneously. In my shoes, there are more suiable tools for the task, that said it can be done. Have a look at this article it speaks on single pass reading which is what you're after. Also look at the recommendation regarding traditional redundancy handled between the database instances